# Suppress filename from output of sha512sum

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files, hashsum, checksum

Maybe it is a trivial question, but in the `man` page I didn't find something useful. I am using Ubuntu and `bash`.

The normal output for `sha512sum testfile` is

```
<hash_code>  testfile
```

How to suppress the filename output? I would like to obtain just

```
<hash_code>
```

Comment: You need help from other tools, like `sha512sum testfile | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There isn't a way to suppress that, but since the SHA is always a single word without spaces you can do:

```
sha512sum testfile | cut -d " " -f 1
```

or e.g.

```
< testfile sha512sum | sed 's/  -//'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
sha512sum testfile | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just add an alias in your `~/.profile` per the Anthon's way of cutting the first argument would help as a permanent solution,

```
sha()
{
sha512sum -- "$1" | cut -d " " -f 1
}
```

To get it working, we obviously would need to run it once as, `. .profile` in `~`.

Now putting only `sha <file_name>` would yield the way you wish it.

Comment: You need to quote `$1`, otherwise, you provide security holes in your function http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906

Answer (score -1):

I also was frustrated by sha??sum stdout format, I used;

```
sha512sum | tr " " "\n" | head -n 1
```